# jQuery get multiple attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element I need to get an array of specific attributes.
For example:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="myClass" data-country="US" data-city="NY" />
```

In this example, I need to get all `data-*` attributes and place them in array (name and value pairs).

In this example, final array would look like this:

```
myDataArray["data-country"] = "US";
myDataArray["data-city"] = "NY";
```

Problem is that these attributes are dynamic, I do not know what attributes will be there at the runtime and I cannot hard code filling of array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call [**data()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to get all data attributes.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kqbFF/)**

```
myDataArray = $('#myDiv').data();
alert(myDataArray["country"]);
alert(myDataArray["city"]);
```

You can iterate through key value pair like this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kqbFF/2/)**

```
arr = $('#myDiv').data();

for(el in arr)
{
    alert("Key >> " + el);
    alert("Value >> " + arr[el]);
}
```

Comment: Is there a selector which would then filter only "data-context-..." attributes or this must be done manually?

Comment: Problem is that I do not know that elements will be "country" or "city", they are dynamic... So i need to iterate through array and know both name and value of each element...

Comment: Check my updated answer to iterate through collection key, value pair.

Answer (score 5):

```
var myDataObject = document.getElementById('myDiv').dataset;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qQWBB/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var data = $('#myDiv').data();
var myDataArray = [];
$.each(data, function(key, val){
        myDataArray['data-' + key] = val;
});
console.log(myDataArray);
```

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cQ4Ty/)***

Comment: Yes, this also work for me... basically all answers are good on this subject!

Many Thanks!