# Extract multiple data from DOM in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a node like this

```
<img src=​"http:​/​/​x.JPG" data-latitude=​"0" data-longitude=​"0">​
```

In jQuery, I can extract two data attribute like this:

```
a=node.data("latitude")
b=node.data("longitude")
```

I was wondering whether there is a way to extract multiple `data` attributes in one time, like this:

```
latLng = node.data([latitude, longitude]) // not working
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672935/jquery-get-multiple-attributes

Comment: There is, but you'd still get an object with keys and values, and would have to access the values by using the keys, so it would really be exactly the same.

Comment: Is expected result an array of values ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
latLng = node.data();
```

this return object

```
{
   latitude:0,
   longitude:0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering whether there is a way to extract multiple data
>   attributes in one time, like this:
>
> `latLng = node.data([latitude, longitude]) // not working`

Note, Not certain if expected result is array of values from `.node.data()` ?

```js
var data = $.map($("img").data(), function(value) {
  return value
});
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<img src=​"http:././.x.JPG" data-latitude="0" data-longitude="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/sqk4986j/2/)**

```
var latLng = $('img').data();
$.each(latLng,function(index,value){
    alert(value); 
});
```